# Finding the exponent of $\lambda$ in Wien's displacement law

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermal-radiation, dimensional-analysis, wavelength, calculus

I am reading [this paper](http://webpages.uidaho.edu/~crepeau/ht2009-88060.pdf) on a short history of the $T^4$ radiation law.

In particular, on page 5,

> By assuming that the wavelength of radiation emitted by a molecule was a function only of
>   its
>   velocity, he [Wien] found,
>    $$\phi_\lambda = \frac{C}{\lambda ^ a} e^{-c/(\lambda v)} $$

I am not entirely sure that I have reproduced is correct. For starters, the paper does not define $\phi$, and I could be confusing $v$ with $\nu$. I think $\phi$ is the spectral energy density, but I'm not quite sure.

However, my bigger question regards the next step of the working.

> By integrating
>   $\phi _ \lambda$
>   over all wavelengths and equating the result
>   with the Stefan-Boltzmann law, he found that the exponent of lambda 8 had to satisfy a = 5.

Mechanically, I do not know how to carry this out. I was thinking:
$$ P = \int_\text{spectrum} \phi _ \lambda d\lambda = \int \frac{C}{\lambda ^ a} e^{-c/(\lambda v)} d \lambda = \sigma T^4 $$

Firstly, I don't know if the first equality is valid (partially because I don't know what $\phi$ is. If $phi$ is indeed the energy density, then I suppose it makes sense that integrating over all wavelengths would give the total energy (power over one second).

But even if what I have written above is correct, I don't know how to evaluate the integral, and I definitely don't see how to recover the fact that $a = 5$

There are many answered questions on this site pertaining to the derivation of Wien's displacement law, and while I can follow those derivations, I am interested in the method to which the linked paper alludes.

**EDIT**
It has been about three weeks since I asked the question, and I still don't understand what is going on. Some of the answers/comments have explained how the integral can be evaluated, using the gamma function, but this leaves me no closer to deducing that $a=5$.

Comment: To evaluate the integral, change variables to $u=c/\lambda v$, which should reduce it to a gamma function.

Comment: To check your answer, in general for $r \in \mathbb{R}$, $\int_0^\infty \frac{d\lambda}{\lambda^a} \, e^{-r/\lambda} = r^{1-a} \Gamma (a-1)$ for $a>1$.